# Phonegap - abrir enlases internos

Tags: phonegap

Estoy usando Phonegap para hacer una copia de un sitio web, lo cual aplico los mismos conceptos para desarrollar una página web a esta app.
Lo que hice es agregar un simple enlace. En una web común tengo index.html y un enlace que se dirije a contactos.html

`<a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a>`

pero en mi caso no funciona, lei que hay un plugin que es inappbrowser, pero creo que solo es para enlaces externos.

Se que es simple lo que pregunto, pero hay cosas que estoy aprendiendo y espero me ayuden.

Gracias

Comment: pues la verdad es que asi como lo tienes deberia de estar funcionando sin problemas, ahora, estas utilizando algún framework o libreria como JQUERY mobile o algo?

Comment: no, solo html limpio, pensaba usar algun framework, pero si ya esto no me funciona, no se que hacer.... voy a revisa todo el codigo por las dudas haya algo que este haciendo mal... hace 4 horas estoy con esto... je... voy a salir a comprar algo y despejarme un poco...

Comment: en todo caso puedes usar framework7 que es bueno para el trabajo

Comment: también Quasar Framework ter serviría

Comment: Gracias, pero no soy bueno en libreria de jquery, por eso lo estoy haciendo sin framework, aunque lei algo de Materialize... el cliente solo quiere una app de su sitio web en la cual haga algunas consultas, algo simple